# CSS3 Transition w/ Firefox/IE

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS:

```
div#dockWrapper{
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: solid 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .35);
    line-height: 0; 
    transition: bottom 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: bottom 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: bottom 0.5s;
}

div#dockWrapper:hover{
    bottom: 77px;
}
```

And this HTML

```
<div id="dockContainer">
    <div id="dockWrapper">
        <div class="cap left">                  
        </div>
        <ul class="osx-dock">
            <li>
            </li>
        </ul>   
    </div>
</div>
```

The transition work fine in google chrome but not in Firefox nor I.E. I'm new to all this CSS3 animations n' stuff so maybe i need to understand some basics. I have other animations on the

```
<li></li>
```

that make a "dock" for my HTML menu and they work fine on all browsers but not the "bottom" one on "dockWrapper".

Thank you,
Simon

Comment: Try adding `bottom: 0;` to the non-hover state. You need a start point . Transitions work best when both states have the same CSS property name being transitioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `bottom: 0` to `div#dockWrapper{`. You need a place to transition from.

According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions, only IE10+ supports the `transition` property.

Answer (score 0):

For non-Firefox/Chrome browsers, I added `-o-transition`, which will let older Opera versions work, and `transition`, which will let IE10 work. IE9 doesn't support transitions.

Firefox, however, requires explicit declaration of both X and Y starting placements. Try this:

```
#dockWrapper{
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    border-bottom: solid 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, .35);
    line-height: 0; 
    transition: bottom 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: bottom 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: bottom 0.5s;
    -o-transition: bottom 0.5s;
    transition: bottom 0.5s;
}
```

I had the same issue animating a menu item before, applying the explicit X/Y declarations solved it. Hopefully it does for you as well.

Side note, I removed the `div` qualifier before `#dockWrapper`. As long as your HTML is valid, you won't have multiple ID declarations, and therefore do not need to qualify the ID. It just makes the CSS slower without any benefit.